# Determine if string appears more than once in string array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array of strings, f.e.

```
string [] letters = { "a", "a", "b", "c" };
```

I need to find a way to determine if any string in the array appears more than once.
I thought the best way is to make a new string-array without the string in question and to use Contains,

```
foreach (string letter in letters)
{
    string [] otherLetters = //?
    if (otherLetters.Contains(letter))
    {
        //etc.     
    }
}
```

but I cannot figure out how.
If anyone has a solution for this or a better approach, please answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx):

```
var lettersWithMultipleOccurences = letters.GroupBy(x => x)
                                           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                           .Select(g => g.Key);
```

This will first group your array using the letters as keys. It then returns only those groups with multiple entries and returns the key of these groups. As a result, you will have an `IEnumerable<string>` containing all letters that occur more than once in the original array. In your sample, this is only "a".

Beware: Because LINQ is implemented using deferred execution, enumerating `lettersWithMultipleOccurences` multiple times, will perform the grouping and filtering multiple times. To avoid this, call `ToList()` on the result:

```
var lettersWithMultipleOccurences = letters.GroupBy(x => x)
                                           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                           .Select(g => g.Key).
                                           .ToList();
```

`lettersWithMultipleOccurences` will now be of type `List<string>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can the LINQ extension methods:

```
if (letters.Distinct().Count() == letters.Count()) {
    // no duplicates
}
```

[`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) removes duplicates. Thus, `letters.Distinct()` would return three elements in your example.

Comment: Tiny bit more efficient would be to use the `.Length` property of the array (`letters.Length`), no need for extension - but surely this is the most elegant and efficient way.

Comment: @Shadow: Good point. I'll leave it at `Count()` for aesthetic reasons, though, since it would look strange to use `Count()` on the left side and `Length` on the right.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. `Enumerable.Count()` uses the `Count` property, if the input is an `ICollection` or an `ICollection<T>` and a .NET array is both.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `HashSet` from the array and compare their sizes:

```
var set = new HashSet(letters);
bool hasDoubleLetters = set.Size == letters.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

A HashSet will give you good performance:

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string letter in letters)
{
    if (hs.Contains(letter))
    {
        //etc. more as once     
    }
    else
    {
           hs.Add(letter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is approximately five times longer than my code and not necessarily more efficient.

Comment: That depends on the filling and size of the initial array.